# PDFsharp MigraDoc Mix: add annotations

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

Two remarks:

- MigraDoc Viewer is a great tool to render a generated PDF
- PDFsharp allows you to insert annotations (Text, etc.) into your PDF.

I would like to see annotations on the Viewer, but need help to get started:

- Are annotations part of the DDL specification?
- What is needed to render PdfAnnotations in MigraDoc Viewer?

  - A new DocumentObject class, implementing Serialize(Serializer)?
- How to get about rendering it? Just the visual part: show the icon
  (possibly transparent), with text closed.

Thanks for hints or any help!

Answer (score 0):

MigraDoc Viewer cannot render PDF. It can show DDL only.

PDF Annotations are not part of DDL and cannot be viewed with the MigraDoc viewer.